# Can't resolve local hosts

Tags: dns, dhcp, hosts

To start with, my Linux or networking knowledge is fairly basic, so it's probably best to assume that I know nothing.

I've been trying (for my own furtherance) to put together some sort of home server, using Ubuntu Server 12.04. I have so far got a DHCP and DNS server, and it can lease IP addresses and resolve Internet domain names, but I cannot (almost certainly due to my own incompetence) resolve the hostnames of local machines. Here is resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

And here, dhcpd.conf:

```
# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "example.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
option domain-name "owen.lan";
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.253;
option routers 192.168.1.254;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.10;
option ntp-servers 192.168.1.10;
option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.10;
option netbios-node-type 8;
}
```

Lastly, the hostfile for the server:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       main-server.home        main-server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts</code>
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

What (probably obvious) point am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a problem I have been dealing with on my newly Ubuntu-ized laptop. I'm not trying to run a DNS or DHCP server on it, but I have been unable to resolve local network addresses, while everything out on the internet resolves fine. What worked for me was changing the Network Service Switch configuration (/etc/nsswitch.conf).

The question that led me to this solution can be found here. Look for the answer which beings "edit the /etc/nsswitch.conf file."
[Why do none of my local servers resolve?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144636/why-do-none-of-my-local-servers-resolve)

...which points to this page for more information:
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-service-switch-config

Simply moving "dns" before "[NOTFOUND=return]" in the "hosts:" string, as recommended, worked for me! Hopefully it's that simple for you too.